# Export to Excel in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, excel

- We are doing an File management project
- We need a same excel format
- Please help me to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) project which provides .NET API to creating Excel files. It comes with a lots of examples so it should be very easy to get started.

Answer (score 1):

There's always [html to excel conversion](http://docraptor.com) which is easier to use (assuming you are comfortable generating html and css) than POI, though POI definitely has features we don't support and is free.

Full disclosure: I helped write the product.